# Insert form fields in a data extension with AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, trigger, ampscript, dataextensions, form

I'm very new to AMPscript and I'm having trouble setting up an HTML form in cloud pages that can pull all the record information in a DE. I also then want to use the DE to trigger an email.
The form also has a subscriber key, but I'm not sure where I can place that in the AMPscript.

My form fields are:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Email
- Country
- Company
- Message

I tried this, Can you help me where I would have gone wrong:

```ampscript
%%[
if RequestParameter("submitted") == "submitted" then
Set @EmailAddr = RequestParameter("Email")
Set @FirstName = RequestParameter("FirstName")
Set @LastName = RequestParameter("LastName")
Set @Company = RequestParameter("Company")
Set @Country = RequestParameter("Country")
Set @Message = RequestParameter("Message")
/* Trigger Send Object Creation */
  SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
  SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
  SET @ts_subkey = @EmailAddr

/* Set the External Key of the Trigger Send Definition */
  SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "53923")
  SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)
  
/* Create the Subscriber Object */
  SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
  SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @EmailAddr)


/* Set SubscriberKey to EmailAddress */
   SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @EmailAddr)


/* Create and Set Attributes */
  SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "ChannelMemberID")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", "100021500")
  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)

  SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "EmailAddress")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", @EmailAddr)
  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)

  SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "FirstName")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", @FirstName)
  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)
  
  SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "LastName")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", @LastName)
  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)
  
    SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "Company")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", @Company)
  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)
  
    SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "Country")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", @Country)
  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)
  
    SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "Message")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", @Message)
  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)

/* Add all Attributes into Array */
  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)

/*Complete the Web API call to trigger send */
  SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)

/* Raise Error if Trigger fails */
  IF @ts_statusCode != "OK" THEN
     RaiseError(@ts_statusMsg, 0, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode)
  ENDIF
  ENDIF
  ]%%
```

Your help is much appreciated!! Thanks!!

Comment: Hi @user77790, you would need to place the ampscript post submit. You can have a look at my article - https://www.salesforcefan.com/post/sending-triggered-email-via-ampscript or Zuzanna's article - https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/25/introduction-to-triggered-sends.

Comment: Hi, 
I'm unable to achieve success. Even though the documentation seems to be simple. @NaveenVM

Comment: I have updated the APM script. Do you think I need to change anything here?

Comment: The email didnt get triggered and the record didn't get added to the DE. I did get the information of the record in the list which is associated with this trigger send.

Answer (score 2):

The form part is missing in your original question so I cannot be sure, but I think you might be mixing up the order of operations.

The AMPscript part needs to be evaluated post form submission, so it needs to be at the beginning of the document and wrapped in a conditional statement so that it only gets evaluated if the form has been submitted.

Try something like this:

```js
%%[
IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN
Set @EmailAddr = RequestParameter("Email")
Set @FirstName = RequestParameter("FirstName")
Set @LastName = RequestParameter("LastName")
Set @Company = RequestParameter("Company")
Set @Country = RequestParameter("Country")
Set @Message = RequestParameter("Message")
/* Trigger Send Object Creation */
  SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
  SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
  SET @ts_subkey = @EmailAddr

/* Set the External Key of the Trigger Send Definition */
  SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "53923")
  SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)
  
/* Create the Subscriber Object */
  SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
  SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @EmailAddr)


/* Set SubscriberKey to EmailAddress */
   SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @EmailAddr)


/* Create and Set Attributes */
  SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "ChannelMemberID")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", "100021500")
  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)

  SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "EmailAddress")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", @EmailAddr)
  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)

  SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "FirstName")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", @FirstName)
  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)
  
  SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "LastName")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", @LastName)
  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)
  
    SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "Company")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", @Company)
  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)
  
    SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "Country")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", @Country)
  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)
  
    SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "Message")
  SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", @Message)
  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)

/* Add all Attributes into Array */
  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)

/*Complete the Web API call to trigger send */
  SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)

Output(v(@ts_statusCode))

/* Raise Error if Trigger fails */
  IF @ts_statusCode != "OK" THEN
     RaiseError(@ts_statusMsg, 0, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode)
  ENDIF
ELSEIF RequestParameter("submitted") == false THEN
  ]%%  

 <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
  <label>First name: </label><input type="text" name="FirstName"><br>
  <label>Last name: </label><input type="text" name="LastName"><br>
  <label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="Email"><br>   
  <label>Company: </label><input type="text" name="Company"><br>
  <label>Country: </label><input type="text" name="Country"><br>   
  <label>Message: </label><input type="text" name="Message"><br>   
  <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Here's an article for your reference: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/09/22/create-a-sales-service-cloud-integrated-lead-capture-form-using-ampscript/

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. I also wanted to check with you how to get success message?

Comment: Just output the status code or the status message using v() function?

Comment: I tried somthing like this 
```js
   set @message = 'Submitted' 
        else 
          set @message = 'Already Submitted'
        endif
else endif
  %%[if @message == 'Submitted' or @message == 'Already Submitted' then ]%%
          %%=v(@message)=%%
          %%[else]%%
     %%[endif]%%
```

Comment: I’ve added the output to my originak answer

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: You would need to add a few more things to prevent from re-submitting the form

Comment: Can you please specify what that would be ?

Comment: It all depends on the behaviour you would expect. If they are only allowed to get 1 email, you could use a lookup to the sendable DE to check if they are already there - then if yes, display the „already submitted” message - but this is a topic for a new thread.